# Match a sting of a various length

Tags: python, regex

I have a block of text that has multiple paragraphs split by a dashed line of various length. I would like to match the line between paragraphs using python. My requirement is as follows:

1. match lines that contain only dashed lines of a various length
2. lines that include dashes and any other char(s) are excluded

Here is a sample text block:

```
Believing neglected so so allowance existence departure in.
In design active temper be uneasy. Thirty for remove plenty 
regard you summer though. He preference connection astonished 
on of yet. ------ Partiality on or continuing in particular principles as. 
Do believing oh disposing to supported allowance we.
-------
Admiration we surrounded possession frequently he. 
Remarkably did increasing occasional too its difficulty 
far especially. Known tiled but sorry joy balls. Bed sudden 

manner indeed fat now feebly. Face do with in need of 
wife paid that be. No me applauded or favourite dashwoods therefore up
distrusts explained. 
----t--
------
And produce say the ten moments parties. Simple innate summer 
fat appear basket his desire joy. Outward clothes promise at gravity 
do excited. 
Sufficient particular impossible by reasonable oh expression is. Yet 
preference 
connection unpleasant yet melancholy but end appearance. And 
excellence partiality 
estimating terminated day everything. 
---------
```

I've tried the following:

```
r"-*.-"g or (.*?)-+
```

however, I match all lines that contain two or more dashes including those that container other characters.

Comment: You can match things of specific length via `CHAR{MINLENGTH,MAXLENGTH}` or `CHAR{LENGTH}`

Comment: You could always use `(?m)^-+[^\S\r\n-]*$`

Answer (score 1):

Simply `r"^[-]+$"` should work. Just remember to specify `MULTILINE` mode for `^` and `$` to match beginning of the line and end of the line respectively, and not just the beginning and end of the whole string.

Actually the last line won't match because it has spaces at the end. If you allow spaces after dashes you can use `r"^[-]+[ ]*$"`.

Another thing - if you also want to match only the lines between paragraphs and not at the very end you can use `r"^[-]+[ ]*$[^\Z]"`

EDIT: Taken from @sln's comment, here's some nuances I forgot about:

1. You can set the `MULTILINE` flag by using `(?m)` at the beginning of the pattern
2. The character class `[^\S\r\n]` matches all whitespace except newline. You can use it instead of `[ ]`, which matches only spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`r'^[^-]*$'`

will match any line that DOES NOT CONTAIN a `-`

you also need to use the multiline flag in order to parse through multi line input with `re.M`

See result here:
https://regex101.com/r/iRkPep/1